# How do I fix the constructor so it works with the parameters I want?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app where there's data sent from one activity to another. I'm using among other ArrayAdapters. I've created a container that contains the parameters I need, but when I write it in the Activity, it doesn't work as it expects something else than I write. The data I'm sending from one activity to another is the input from the user. I'm using the input to filter a ListView I've made. So my question is, how do I fix the constructor, so it can work with the parameters I need? I know I've uploaded a lot of code, but I think it's relevant.

This is my Container:

```
public class Container{
public final String søgeord;
public final String itemname;
public final Integer imgid;
Container(String søgeord, String itemname, Integer imgid){
    this.søgeord=søgeord;
    this.itemname = itemname;
    this.imgid = imgid;
 }
}
```

This is the CustomListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Container>{

private final Activity context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, Container[] containers) {
        super(context, R.layout.mylist, containers);
        this.context=context;
    }
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Container currentItem = getItem(position);

    txtTitle.setText(currentItem.itemname);
    imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.imgid);
    extratxt.setText(currentItem.itemname);
    return view;

 };
}
```

This is the Activity I send data from, and have commented beside the constructor:

```
public class Forside extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Liste{

CustomListAdapter listAdapter;
EditText filterText;

ImageButton sog;
EditText sogefelt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forside);

    filterText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sogefelt);
    ListView itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter (this, annoncer, imageId, null); //this is the constructor
    sog = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sog);
    sog.setOnClickListener(this);
    sogefelt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sogefelt);

    itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position==0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Forside.this, Sogeresultater.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

}

public void onClick (View v){
    if (v == sog){
        String søgeord = sogefelt.getText().toString();
        ArrayList<String> resultater = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String i: annoncer) {
            if (i.toUpperCase().contains(søgeord.toUpperCase()))
                resultater.add(i);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Sogeresultater.class);
        intent.putExtra("søg", resultater.toArray(new String[resultater.size()]));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.Forside) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Forside.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.Logind){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Log_Ind.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (id==R.id.Opretbruger) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Opret_bruger.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return true;
 }
}
```

Last but not least, this is the Activity I send data to:

```
public class Sogeresultater extends AppCompatActivity implements Liste{

CustomListAdapter listAdapter;
EditText filterText;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);


    final String[] søgestreng = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("søg");


    filterText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sogefelt);
    ListView itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter (this, annoncer, imageId, søgestreng); //this also the constructor, here I want "søgestreng", as it's the input from the user

    itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Sogeresultater.this.listAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.Forside) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

[image: This is the error]

Comment: Why is it a bad question?

Comment: If you want that other people can't work with your code then keep using variable names like `søgeord`. I don't have that letter on my keyboard. PS: What are the parameters you want? What stops you from changing the constructor?

Comment: Ok, I'll from now on

Comment: @zapl - don't be rude, not everyone programs in English. Anyways, @Hudhud, I'm not sure what exactly your issue is, but I noticed in the custom list adapter you don't use `currentitem.søgeord`

Comment: In the `Sogeresultater` class, I want the parameters as showed in the code as in this class I recieve some data from `Forside` class. The problem is that it says that it expects something else. Have uploaded an image of the error.

Comment: @cricket_007, yes that's true cause it's just the input from a user/the word a person writes in the editText

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh, you're right I can read that as quite rude but it wasn't meant to sound that bad. Common problem when I try to write "formal" and not put :)s all over the place to "fix" that.

Comment: How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CustomListAdapter` is only capable of dealing with an array of `Container`s. Each container seems to have the properties you try to supply to the adapter's constructor.

To make it work you'll either need to turn the data you have into the format it expects: (i.e. transform the `String[]` array into a `Container[]` array)

```
List<Container> containers = new ArrayList<Container>();
for (String sogething : søgestreng) {
    String itemname = "I don't know"; // ?
    Integer imgid = 1234; // ?
    Container container = new Container(sogething, itemname, imgid);
    containers.add(container);
}
Container[] array = containers.toArray(new Container[containers.size()]);
listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, array);
```

Or you need to change the existing / add another constructor that is happy with just a `String[]` array instead of a full `Container` array. But since your Adapter needs the things defined in `Container` you'll have to come up with a way to substitute / load the data that belongs to the string.